# How to install fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-262 patch in EAP 6.4 server

Tags: jbossfuse, jboss-eap-6

Could you please help me in installing fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-262 patch in EAP 6.4 server. I have already installed fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-187, now I need to install fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-262.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You run fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-262.jar and it will apply the upgrade. For example:

```
java -jar fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-262.jar /opt/jboss-eap-6.4
```

I updated the answer as it seems you hit a problem:

```
C:\Temp\Selva\Installations\EAP_Server_6.4>java -jar 
M:\Selva\Software\fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-262.jar Error: Unable to determine current fuse patch version

C:\Temp\Selva\Installations\EAP_Server_6.4>
```

If I remember correctly, there's a bug in the installer on Windows. There's a knowledge base article which explains how to resolve the problem here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2960241.

Comment: Thank you James, It worked for me. And also can you please share me the link from where I could download patch fuse-eap-installer-6.3.0.redhat-310.jar.

Comment: You can find the 310 release via the Red Hat customer portal JBoss Fuse downloads area. It's 'Rollup 5' under the 'Security Advisories' tab.